# Singularity.gs div background not showing

Tags: html, css, user-interface, grid, singularitygs

I am building a website using singularity.gs which I am fairly new to.
I am having trouble giving a div a background-color, this is my html structure:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/205xt1i.jpg , the "green" part is my about div.

```
<div class="about">
    <div class="photo">
        <img class="photoBorder" src="images/foto_jeroen.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Hello I'm Jeroen Druw&eacute</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To achieve this affect is had to set a height for the div:

```
@include breakpoint(70em) { 
 .about {
   height: 340px; //This property will set the height of the div
 }

.about .photo {
   padding: 1em;
   @include grid-span(2, 4);
 }

.about .text {
   padding-top: 7em;
   padding-left: 1em;
   display: inline;
   @include grid-span(4, 6);
}}
```

If I remove the "height:340px" no background will be drawn:

http://oi39.tinypic.com/2s16ezl.jpg (only my thin borderline)

Is there a way to let the div wrap its height around its content (.photo,.text)?

Note: if i remove @include grid-span for .photo and .text the background shows but I do not want to lose the singularity functionality

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't span the container.

The problem you experience happens because **Singularity columns are `float`ed**, and **floated elements are taken out of *the flow***. This means that the container does not "know" about your columns any more, so it behaves like an empty element.

There's a property called `clear` that positions an element below any nearby floated element. If you create an extra element inside the container after all your columns, the `clear: both;` rule applied to it will push it below the floated columns, effectively stretching the container as high as columns are:

```
<div class="about">
    <div class="photo">
        <img class="photoBorder" src="images/foto_jeroen.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Hello I'm Jeroen Druw&eacute</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class=clear></div>
</div>
```

```css
.clear { clear: both; }
```

But don't add an extra element, that's not semantic. Instead, use the `:after` pseudo element that appears at the end of an element's **contents**. Using `:after` is just like creating a blank element at the end of element's contents.

```
.about {
  &:after {
    content: ''; // This is required for the pseudo-element to exist
    display: block; // Default display is inline, have to change that for `clear` to work.
    clear: both; // Yay, magic!
  }
}
```

This technique is called "[clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)".

This can be done even simpler with the multi-purpose [Toolkit](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#toolkit) extension from Team Sass, the authors of Singularity:

```
@import 'toolkit';
.about { @extend %toolkit-micro; }
```

The `%toolkit-micro` extendable [has](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#clearfix) some additional rules that makes the clearfix trick work in older browsers. There's also the `%clearfix-legacy` extendable that works even in ancient browsers.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment! I have found another way earlier to fix it, @include grid-span(12, 1) in the "about" div. What solution is better practice?

Comment: Clearfixing is cleaner. Your solution floats the container snd limits its size. Also, you would need to clearfix container's container.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
Forgot to add an @include grid-span(12, 1); for my .about